# Data density of audio steganography

Tags: audio, steganography

How many bytes can be stored per minute of audio using any method of steganography with a disregard to detectability or any other factor e.g if the original audio begins to sound different

Comment: I mean, if you're going to disregard quality degradation, then you may as well convert all the original bytes with your secret bytes. How many bytes there are in a minute of an audio file depends on the format, compression, sample rate, bitrate, etc. You can find online calculators that do for you. But the question as it currently stands is vague and nothing more than a simple arithmetic computation.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography